# Does std::vector::erase make pointers invalid?

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector, erase

Let's say I have a `std::vector<Node*> nodes;` and a `std::vector<Unit*> units;`. Each node points to a unit and each unit points back to the node, so they are connected. But what happens when I use **erase** to remove an element from the middle of either array? If it resizes the array, does that mean it removes all of the elements, stores them in some buffer and builds back the resized array? So if I use erase on nodes, the pointers in units would become invalid?

Answer (score 2):

Removing or inserting elements from or into the middle of a vector moves all the higher elements down or up appropriately. But since you're just moving pointers around, that's a nearly trivial operation. Nothing happens to the other pointers (the ones you aren't erasing), and nothing happens to any of the *pointees*.

Answer (score 2):

Erasing an element from a vector of pointers does not call a delete on the object, pointed to by the pointer. Your Node<->Unit pointers will stay valid.

Answer (score 1):

Using erase on a vector invalidates the pointers for all the elements after the erased element.

The other elements will be shifted down or up in memory when you use erase/insert in the middle of a vector, and using those pointers will now yield an undefined behavior.

If you want to keep those pointers valid, your options are:

1. After erasing, loop through the vector you just used erase on and re-assign the element pointers to the other vector.
2. Use a list. list.erase() does not invalidate pointers/iterators except for the element you are erasing, so make sure you delete the pointer of the item you erased in your other vector.

The drawback with lists is they don't have random access, so you'll need to iterate through, no list[] for you.

Hope this helps.